# Two Different models with the some of same properties cause problems in Swift

Tags: json, swift, struct, codable

i have two different models with slightly different properties in my project. But when i use them without default values in one of the model, it gives error `Type 'Instructions' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` if i just remove = "" from the property summary inside Instructions model. Why this happens and how to overcome? Because in this way, even if i get data from API, it doesn't overwrite the default value.

**INSTRUCTIONS MODEL**

```
struct Instructions: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    
    let vegetarian: Bool = false
    let vegan: Bool = false
    let glutenFree: Bool = false
    let dairyFree: Bool = false
    let veryHealthy: Bool = false
    let cheap: Bool = false
    let veryPopular: Bool = false
    let sustainable: Bool = false
    let lowFodmap: Bool = false
    let weightWatcherSmartPoints: Int = 0
    let gaps: String = ""
    let preparationMinutes: Int = 0
    let cookingMinutes: Int = 0
    let aggregateLikes: Int = 0
    let healthScore: Int = 0
    let creditsText: String = ""
    let license: String = ""
    let sourceName: String = ""
    let pricePerServing: Double = 0
    let extendedIngredients: [ExtendedIngredient]
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let readyInMinutes: Int = 0
    let servings: Int = 0
    let sourceUrl: String = ""
    let image: String
    let imageType: String
    let summary: String = ""
    let cuisines: [String] = []
    let dishTypes: [String] = []
    let diets: [String] = []
    let occasions: [String] = []
    let winePairing: WinePairing?
    let instructions: String = ""
    let analyzedInstructions: [AnalyzedInstructions]
    let originalId: Int? = 0
    let spoonacularScore: Double = 0
    let spoonacularSourceUrl: String = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, image, imageType, winePairing, analyzedInstructions, extendedIngredients
    }
}

struct ExtendedIngredient: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let aisle: String
    let image: String
    let consistency: String
    let name: String
    let nameClean: String
    let original: String
    let originalName: String
    let amount: Double
    let unit: String
    let meta: [String]
    let measures: Measures
}

struct Measures: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let us: Measure
    let metric: Measure
}

struct Measure: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let amount: Double
    let unitShort: String
    let unitLong: String
}

struct WinePairing: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let pairedWines: [String]
    let pairingText: String
    let productMatches: [ProductMatch]
}

struct ProductMatch: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
}

struct AnalyzedInstructions: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let name: String
    let steps: [Steps]
}

struct Steps: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let number: Int
    let step: String
    let ingredients: [Ingredients]
    let equipment: [Equipments]
    let length: Lengths?
}

struct Ingredients: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let localizedName: String
    let image: String
}

struct Equipments: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let localizedName: String
    let image: String
}

struct Lengths: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let number: Int
    let unit: String
}
```

**RECIPE MODEL**

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct RecipeResults: Codable {
    let results: [Recipe]
    let offset, number, totalResults: Int
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Recipe: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let vegetarian, vegan, glutenFree, dairyFree: Bool
    let veryHealthy, cheap, veryPopular, sustainable: Bool
    let lowFodmap: Bool
    let weightWatcherSmartPoints: Int
    let gaps: String
    let preparationMinutes, cookingMinutes, aggregateLikes, healthScore: Int
    let creditsText, sourceName: String
    let pricePerServing: Double
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let readyInMinutes, servings: Int
    let sourceURL: String
    let image: String
    let imageType, summary: String
    let dishTypes, diets: [String]
    let analyzedInstructions: [AnalyzedInstruction]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vegetarian, vegan, glutenFree, dairyFree, veryHealthy, cheap, veryPopular, sustainable, lowFodmap, weightWatcherSmartPoints, gaps, preparationMinutes, cookingMinutes, aggregateLikes, healthScore, creditsText, sourceName, pricePerServing, id, title, readyInMinutes, servings
        case sourceURL = "sourceUrl"
        case image, imageType, summary, dishTypes, diets, analyzedInstructions
    }
}

// MARK: - AnalyzedInstruction
struct AnalyzedInstruction: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let name: String
    let steps: [Step]
}

// MARK: - Step
struct Step: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let number: Int
    let step: String
    let ingredients, equipment: [Ent]
    let length: Length?
}

// MARK: - Ent
struct Ent: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name, localizedName, image: String
    let temperature: Length?
}

// MARK: - Length
struct Length: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let number: Int
    let unit: String
}
```

Comment: Post code as text.

Comment: i try that but it will be too long. i dont know how to do it in a scrolling box

Comment: Then edit your models and only include only enough properties necessary to understand the issue. That said, scrolling should be enabled automatically when the code is long

Comment: let me try. i m doing it now. 
Edit: Done!

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Show the full error message.
 You need to use `var` (not `let`) for those properties you want to set using your API.

Comment: What I mean is, in your `struct Instructions` declare the properties, such as,
 `let vegetarian: Bool` or use `var vegetarian: Bool = false` etc...
 If you have a `let` and if you give it a value, it can never change again.
 What you have, are not what you call `default` values, they are constants if you use `let`.

Comment: There's enough information here to answer the question, so I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using custom coding keys for properties in `InstructionsModel`. In order to conform to to `Codable` protocol you need to define all properties and their custom keys, or if your property names are the same as JSON keys, just remove that enum.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, title, image, imageType, winePairing, analyzedInstructions, extendedIngredients
}
```

Comment: I was just going to answer this so upvoted. I assume the easiest way forward is to remove the enum

Comment: Agree, that would be the easiest way

Comment: And to further explain the error, when you use the CodingKey enum then the compiler will generate an init using the fields in the enum and that is why every other property not in the enum must have a default values since they won't get set in the init

Comment: But will then need to remove all the assignments because properties that are assigned values are ignored on decoding.

Comment: If you want to control the whole flow just define all keys in that enum.

Comment: You got the explanation why from @JoakimDanielson